# Remove Modal View Controller when Application becomes active

Tags: iphone, ios, modalviewcontroller, multitasking

In my app I have a button, when the user clicks it, it brings up a modal view controller which gets the user's location (with a `UIActivityIndicator` and image on). When it has there location it will send them off to another application.

This works well on older devices (without multi-tasking) because the app simply re-launches back to it's previous state after I go back to it.

However on devices that have multi-tasking, when I resume the app, the view that tells the user it's getting their location is still there - which is not at all desired.

My first idea was to set a BOOL when it was about to fire them off to the other app, and then in the `viewDidAppear`, if the BOOL is true, dismiss the modal view.

That would work, if `viewDidAppear` got called when an app resumes active. As I have just learnt, it doesn't.

Is there a method that view controllers can respond to when the app resumes active to that view? Or, will I have to set up delegation etc with the app delegate? If so, can you explain how I would do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can send a notification when the app becomes active and listen to it into your modalviewcontroller. I think this is the easiest way.

```
// Into the app delegate
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ApplicationDidBecomeActive" object:nil];
}

// Into your modal view controller register it for the given notification
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive:) name:@"ApplicationDidBecomeActive" object:nil];

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification
{
//...
}
```

Otherwise you can disable the background mode of your application by setting the "UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend" key to YES in the info.plist file.